# How to hide Cloud Run behind Identity-Aware Proxy without a domain name for the load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, identity-aware-proxy

I followed the docs ([Setting up a load balancer with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#ssl_certificate_resource), and [Setting up an external HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto#load-balancer)) and successfully enabled IAP on a load balancer, which has Cloud Run as a backend.

It seems that for IAP to work, the frontend of the load balancer needs to be configured for HTTPS, which in turn requires owning a domain.

Is there a way to still have IAP on Cloud Run without specifically registering a domain?

Comment: If you do not specify a domain name for the SSL certificate, how do you expect HTTPS to work? For testing, you can get a free domain name at FreeNom: https://www.freenom.com/en/index.html

Comment: You can't have a valid TLS certificate (trusted by root providers) without having a domain. You can always self-sign a TLS certificate for an IP address and use it on the LB, but it won't work on people's browsers etc.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google That's what I was afraid of. It's unfortunate to have to have a domain just for this purpose but it's manageable.